# "Save config" is not working in Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

After changing in Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer

```
Merge JavaScript Files = Yes
Merge CSS Files = Yes
```

My site is not browsing correctly.

I believe returning back to

```
Merge JavaScript Files = No
Merge CSS Files = No
```

may help but “Save Config” button is not working any more..

Through debug console I see issue with on-click
with button  id="id_5552aa811a9448075ead92b4a88ba8c2"

Please help

Comment: Careful when merging JS files, as you may get conflicts between jQuery and Prototype at times, as they both use "$"

Answer (score 0):

If you are really desperate to undo/turn off the Javascript & CSS file merging, you can change the values directly in the database

> Proceed with caution changing values directly on production databases.

Run the query below to locate the 2 rows where the config value is stored and change the values back to `0`. Or you can just manually go to `core_config_data` and find rows with the following paths and set them to `0`.

**SQL Query:**

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data
WHERE path LIKE '%merge_%'`

**path column:**

`dev/js/merge_files
dev/css/merge_css_files`

**Screenshot of table:**
[image: Sequel Pro]